# How to access strings from C in GraalVM?

Tags: scala, llvm, gnat, graalvm

How do I access strings from C in GraalVM?
I attached an example in Ada, where the *Hello* function is exported.

**test.ads**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

with Interfaces.C;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

package Test is

    package C renames Interfaces.C;

    function Hello return C.Strings.chars_ptr
        is (C.Strings.New_String ("abcdef"))
        with Export => True, Convention => C, External_Name => "hello";

end Test;
```

**HelloGraal.scala**

```
object HelloGraal {
  val polyglot: Context = Context.newBuilder()
    .allowAllAccess(true)
    .option("llvm.libraries", "./gnat-llvm/llvm-interface/lib/rts-native/adalib/libgnat.dylib")
    .build()

  def loadBcFile(file: File): Value = {
    val source = Source.newBuilder("llvm", file).build()
    polyglot.eval(source)
  }
  val test: Value = loadBcFile(new File("./ada/test.bc"))

  val hello = test.getMember("hello")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(hello.execute())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Ada very well, but I can give the answer for C. I hope someone knowledgeable in Ada can "translate" that ;)

In LLVM bitcode, there is no explicit `string` type, there is just `i8*`, and not every `i8*` is necessarily a string, it could also just be an arbitrary pointer. Because of that, you have to do the conversion manually.

There are two API functions for converting "C" strings to "polyglot" string values: `polyglot_from_string` converts a zero-terminated string, and `polyglot_from_string_n` converts a string with given length.

These functions are declared in `polyglot.h` (in `graalvm/jre/languages/llvm/include`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried to "translate" it to Ada, however, I get the following error: `Exception in thread "main" org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.AssertionError: com.oracle.truffle.llvm.runtime.NFIContextExtension$UnsupportedNativeTypeException: unsupported type %{[0 x i8]*, %{i32, i32}*} in native interop`

Comment: Looks like there is some native call (probably to the ada runtime) with a struct-by-value argument (i.e. `struct Foo` instead of `struct Foo *`). This is not yet supported by the Truffle native interface (but on our todo-list). One way around that is to try to also compile the runtime libraries to bitcode.

Can you provide a full reproducer and report a bug on github? That way I can verify whether that's really the problem. This is definitely something we need to fix on our side.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the [`Value`](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/index.html?org/graalvm/polyglot/Value.html) class from `org.graalvm.polyglot` exposes methods that let you query its type and also to convert it to the given type. In this case, you want to use `Value#asString()`, so in your example

```
hello.execute().asString()
```

In reality, it depends on what the LLVM interpreter gives you back and if it supports `asString`. It may be just a byte array, which you could read byte-by-byte using `Value#getArrayElement`. It may be a pointer to off-heap memory (which would never happen in managed LLVM mode), which you can read using `Value#asNativePointer`.

Roland's answer gives more detailed description.